# Copying data from one workbook to another - with extras

Tags: excel, copying, pasting, vba

I am looking for a solution to create the code to copy data from Workbook 1 Sheet 1 to another workbook that will be closed. I also want to make sure that the data being pasted is in the next empty row, so in essence:

Active workbook 1, sheet 1 copy any data from row 2 to the last row
Paste in to inactive workbook 2 in the first row that is empty

Hope this make sense!

Answer (score 0):

Record this task with Excel macro Recorder and you have 90% of your code. To make sure you got the last empty row place the Cursor in Cell A1, press Button `END` and then `Cursor down`.

This site is to help If you need some coder service please use [other Portals like here](https://www.google.de/search?q=freelancers&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:de-DE:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&gws_rd=cr&ei=CibRWMGaIYfmgAaRq4ygBw#spf=1)